# How can I authenticate google cloud sdk onto my docker image?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-iam

My problem is I get an api error when I run my docker image: "ApiError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage Object.

- Verified my ServiceAccountKey.json had the correct credentials and IAM roles (Firebase Admin SDK Service Agent, Service Account Token Creator, Storage Admin, Storage Object Admin).
- on the Docker file I install google Cloud SDK and authenticate it by
  RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
  ENV PATH $PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin
  RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=ServiceAccountKey.json
  RUN gcloud --quiet config set project myproject
- I have my env variables handled by dotenv and the .env file is copied into the image
- my image is built without any errors
- My code works 100% fine locally and works as follows

1. Triggers on Updates on documents in a collection
2. Gets a latex template from a bucket
3. Converts the Latex document to a pdf
4. Save the pdf into the another bucket for processed pdfs
5. Email the pdf
   The docker image is able to look for the update triggers correctly. It even finds the template in the bucket. The issue lies in it not being able to download the template from the bucket because of the ERROR message above

Comment: What IAM permissions are given to the the service account?

Comment: Why you download gcloud? Why don't you simply use the service account directly with your code? Where us your container running?

Comment: IAM permissions are ("Firebase ADMIN SDK ADMINSTRATOR SERVICE AGENT, SERVICE ACCOUNT TOKEN CREATOR, STORAGE ADMIN").  
I downloaded gcloud because I was trying to use it as a solution for the docker image. In the code, it works locally. I am running the container on docker desktop

Comment: Thank you, the issue was in my code. not the dockerfile